# No view found for id 0x7f0b006b from FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to open a fragment from FragmentActivity. I have implmented NavigationDrawer. From Main Activity I opened FragmentActivity (LINK_New.java) and from there I want to open a Fragment (LINK_Create.java).

The main Navigation DrawList has this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

FRAME_CONTAINER IS ONLY AVAILABLE IN THE ABOVE XML.

XML for LINK_New & LINK_Create: it is just Linear Layout with TextBox and Image stuff in it.

I am trying this:

```
        fragment = new LINK_Create();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager2.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

For which I am getting below error:

```
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620): Process: com.ylg.LINK, PID: 20620
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b006b (com.ylg.LINK:id/frame_container) for fragment LINK_Create{3093cc8e #0 id=0x7f0b006b}
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-07 13:36:19.142: E/AndroidRuntime(20620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My LINK_New FRAGMENTACTIVITY has the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoactionbar);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.account_anew));

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundcolor)));

        setContentView(R.layout.link_new)   
}
```

On BackPressed inside LINK_New.java I am calling the fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
         fragment = new LINK_Create();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager2.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
  }
```

I tried all the solutions that are available on SO I am not able to figure out a solution for the above issue.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your layout is not missing view with `R.id.frame_container` id?

Comment: Or maybe you are calling this stuff too early. Code shown is OK.

Comment: please show entire `onCreate()` method **and** the layout you set in `setContentView()` BEFORE you add the fragment

Comment: @Ziem: Layout as in fragment XML: If so I don't frame_Container there.  The main Navigation Drawer has the frame_Container

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Didn't understand your question are asking the code of LINK_CREATE FRAGMENT or the FRAGMENT ACTIVITY (The activity from which I am calling Link_Create?

Comment: the **activity** as it is the only thing that can have a `setContentView` in its `onCreate`, and also as `onCreateView` of Fragment isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce : I have updated my question with SetContentView on Create

Comment: `On BackPressed inside LINK_New.java` no, this logic with the fragment transaction should be in the Activity. You are using the Fragment's fragment manager instead of the Activity's. The fragment has no `frame_container`, the Activity does.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the fragment's fragment manager, instead of the Activity's. So, use the Activity's instead.

FragmentActivity:

```
public void replaceWith(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
        .commit();
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    ((YourFragmentActivity)getActivity()).replaceWith(new LINK_Create());
}
```

This is the quick solution to the problem, anyways.

Normally I'd use `Otto` and send an event

FragmentActivity:

```
@Subscribe
public void onLinkFragmentBackPressed(LINK_New.BackPressedEvent e) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new LINK_Create())
        .commit();
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SingletonBus.INSTANCE.post(new BackPressedEvent());
}
```

Comment: Looks like you miss understood the java files or I think I am getting confused Anyways I will explain again:

LINK_NEW is a FragmentActivity from here I want to call or open  LINK_Create which is Fragment - When I am doing the above which is on my question I am getting No View.  Why do I have to call OnBackpressed inside Fragment.

Comment: onBackpressed is inside LINK_New.java which is a fragmentactivity when I press back button I want the Link_Create (fragment) to be opened.

Comment: ....wait, link_new is an activity, and link create is a fragment? You seriously need a better naming convention,

Comment: Yep. Link_NEW is an FragmentActivity and Link_Create is Fragment.

Comment: From LINK_New (FragmentActivity) I am trying to goto Link_Create (Fragment) by pressing back button. That is where I am stuck now.